# Removing sidebar component on Home Page in customer portal

Tags: customer-portal

I am working on Customer Portal.on my home page in customer portal i dont want to include sidebar component.but still its leaving space in left hand side.Can we remove this space or not?if yes how?what configuration i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you removing the component from the relevant page layout or just hiding it somehow? If it's been removed from the layout then it shouldn't leave any kind of space.

Comment: i don't want sidebar component on my home page.on other pages i require it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug and inspect the page. Then in your footer that you upload to the customer portal - write CSS that changes the ID of that sidebar space to a width of 0%. This will work until salesforce later updates to the customer portal; they have discontinued using it and moved to communities so maybe you can be assured they wont update it anymore. Who knows?

This worked for me to remove my sidebar space.

Answer (score -1):

How are you removing it?

I believe if you use the vf page tag with the attributes of:

```
<apex:page showHeaders="true" sidebar="false">
```

that should turn offt the sidebar and float everything back to the left.

Comment: The home page is not a custom visualforce page.